# iOS: ScrollView detect dragging progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a ScrollView with bounce & bounce horizontally on. I'd like to fade out a label inside it, based on the direction of dragging. If the user drags the ScrollView to the left it will fade out, if right - it will fade in.

I think I have to implement a `scrollViewDidScroll` method where I check whether `scrollView.dragging` is `true`, but afterwards, I'm unsure how to calculate the dragging direction and progress. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

calculate change of the contentOffSet

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static CGFloat originalOffSetX = 0.0;
    if (scrollView.contentOffSet.x - originalOffSetX > 0) {
        //moving right
    } else {
        //left
    }
    originalOffSetX = scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
}
```